# Dynamic tooltip value extraction using chrome vba selenium

Tags: vba, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am facing issue in dynamic tooltip value using vba chrome selenium,now issue in other data extraction as everything is smooth but facing issue in dynamic tool tip value.My code is given below.

```
d.Get "https://norway.dealroom.co/companies/nortech_1"
Sleep 200
'On Error Resume Next
'------------------------------------------
'For i = 1 To 65

'Set my_data = d.FindElementsByClass("to_hasTooltip")
'For Each Item In my_data
'href11 = Item.Attribute("href")
'
'Dim news As String
'news = href11 & "{}" & "{}" & url & "}{"
'news1 = MyClean(news)
'
'news1 = Replace(news1, "{}", vbTab)
'news1 = Replace(news1, "}{", vbLf)
'
'Fileout.write news1
'href11 = ""
'Next
'd.FindElementByCss("a.to_hasTooltip:nth-child(7)").Click
'd.FindElementByCss("a.to_hasTooltip:nth-child(5)").Click
'Next
'------------------------------------------
d.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/main/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/span").Click

ab = d.FindElementByClass("tooltip-wraper--open").text
MsgBox (ab)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code, working fine.
Explanation - Using action class, performing mouse hover on required element and then getting tooltip text.
#output : Checked at 29 Jun 2023 by Louis Geoffroy-Terryn

```
import the webdriver
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# get method to launch the URL
driver.get("https://norway.dealroom.co/companies/nortech_1")
# to scroll with Javascript executor

driver.execute_script('return document.title')
time.sleep(10)
hoverable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='icon-font icon-checkmark verified-icon "
                                          "verified-icon--verified']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(hoverable).perform()
ab = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//body/div[@class='drop-down-portal']/div[@role='dialog']/div["
                                  "@class='balloon-dialog__content balloon-dialog__content--tooltip']/span[1]").text
print(ab)
```